# django: url routing to hardcoded static and html files

Tags: django, static-files, hardcoded

I have a legacy project with a bunch of html files and static files (css, images, js, videos ...). All links in those html files are relative and hardcoded:

"css/main.css" or "img/my_img.jpg" etc.

I need to run that project using django.

I cannot change all those links to kind of

```
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

but all recipes I found in internet suggest using exactly that method.

How can I:

1) route hardcoded urls like "css/main.css"

2) route hardcoded urls like "another.html" ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with much ease like this`<!--lets' say image-->
<img src="{% static 'static/images/image1.png' %}">`.Please make sure the file directories match with that in the code.
Please visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files for detailed info